# ILLUSTRATOR: I Can't Divide Shapes The Way I Want

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

### **ILLUSTRATOR: I Can't Divide Shapes The Way I Want**

I'm trying get a mesh of two shapes, but no matter what Pathfinder I use, I can't get the desired effect.

**What I've Tried:**

• Pathfinders (all of them)

• Object > Path > Divide Objects Below

**Example:**
[image: Example]

Comment: Sometimes I wish Illustrator worked more like a cad software. There are plugins that bring cad features to AI, but they are super expensive, so I've never tried them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **Shape Builder Tool**. Select both shapes and just <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> click the piece you want to remove. Then click-drag (no Option/Alt) across the pieces you want to join.

https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/shape-builder-easy.html

Comment: Thanks A TON! This is the first time I've used the Shape Builder Tool and it's opening up a ton of new possibilities for me!

Comment: Glad I could help. :) It's really just sort of Pathfinder unite and subtract in a brush. Very handy for those little joins and deletions that Pathfinder may struggle with.